# Input variable not being reset with each iteration

Tags: java

In my code, I am testing palidromes, but my input variable is not being reset with each iteration. The test works perfectly the first time, but with the same input, it comes out wrong.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int i;
System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
String pal = input.nextLine();
String reverse = "";
boolean isFalse = false;

while (!isFalse) {
    if (pal.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Empty line read - Goodbye!");
        isFalse = true;
    }
    if (pal.length() > 0) {
        for (i = pal.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            reverse = reverse + pal.charAt(i);
        }
        if (pal.equals(reverse)) {
            System.out.println(pal + " is a palidrome");
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println(pal + " is not a palidrome");
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        pal = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

pal is the input variable. While debugging, I printed the results of pal. 1331 comes out as a palidrome, but as I reentered 1331, the program outputs a false statement. Any suggestions?
Edit: I added the rest of the code above the while loop

Comment: Hard to tell with the code you posted but it looks like this may be the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] - the current code is missing a bunch of stuff...

Comment: Have you carefully debugged, either on paper, or with the debugger? Have you checked your assumptions regarding what specifically is contained in `pal`, the result of the `nextLine` call? Unrelated, but maybe change the name of `isFalse` to something like `shouldContinue`, and set it to `false` when you shouldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reset variable `reverse` by writing `reverse = "";` before the for loop:

```
reverse = "";
for (i = pal.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    reverse += pal.charAt(i);
}
```